# Windows Home Server 2011 fails to boot on new hardware

Tags: system-recovery, windows-home-server

I had to change the motherboard, CPU and memory in my WHS 2011 recently, but after doing so it wont boot up. After the BIOS screen, the monitor is black for a moment and then, the system automatically restarts. On the restart I have to option to repair the computer. However, when in the recovery mode, I only have the option to repair the computer from a system image - which I dont have! If I try to boot from the installation media and then select a system repair, the only option is to use a system image as well.

Is there any way to reapir a WHS 2011 installation without having a system image?

Answer (score 0):

You can't expect WHS2011 to boot on new hardware - in can be made to boot, but that's for experts. Better to reinstall WHS2011. If you wish to save data, you can disconnect all disks except the one you wish to install on - or you might move your hard disk(s) temporary to another computer and copy data off the disk(s). Remember that reinstalling WH2011 will wipe your disk(s) clean.

Comment: I would love to see the 'expert' solution to this problem as I don't want to settle for the old format and reinstall solution...

Comment: I'm no expert, but as far as I know you have to install the drivers corresponding to your new hardware instead the present ones - i.e. the ones from your old hardware.